# Dropbox API finding new/changed files

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to setup a webhook from dropbox to notify my server whenever a new file is uploaded.
There are 1000's of files being shared but < 100 everyday and I only want to find the new files of a certain type that have been added or modified since the last check.
The webhook sends the userid when the file is added but doesn't indicate a file name.
Is there anyway using the list_folder api, or using another api to find out what file has been changed since a certain date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dropbox webhooks](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks) only tell you that something changed, but not what specifically changed.

You can use these in conjunction with [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue)] to see what changed. The [webhooks documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks) and the [Content Access Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/content-access-guide#updates) have more information about this.

In short, the basic flow would be like this:

- The user connects the app to their account, and the app saves the resulting access token for that user.
- The app gets the current state of the account using [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue)], and stores the latest returned cursor.
- The user makes changes in their account.
- Dropbox notifies the app of changes in the user's account using a webhook notification.
- The app receives the webhook notification and looks up the corresponding access token and cursor for the specified user.
- The app calls [/2/files/list_folder/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue) using the cursor to retrieve only what changed since it last called, and again stores the latest returned cursor.
- (Repeat)

Comment: So I need to do a /2/files/list_folder[/continue], and persist the cursor.  When the webhook does a callback I can use that cursor and only puled what's changed.  That's a good plan.